# UIToolBar not displaying

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I'm trying to build an app that has a webview with a top `UIToolBar`. This app is meant for internal use at our company and I was tasked with building this. This particular webview comes up if a user wants to read the FAQ, which are loaded from our internal website. This webview loads as a modal and needs a button in the `UIToolBar` to dismiss it. However, I'm not having any luck.

The current implementation just displays http://www.google.com without the `UIToolBar`. What am I doing wrong?

**LoginWebviewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginWebViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**LoginWebviewController.m**

```
#import "LoginWebViewController.h"

@interface LoginWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginWebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Log in";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(barButtonBackPressed:)];

    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768)];
    NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
}

-(void)barButtonBackPressed:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Check whether `navigationController` nil or not

Comment: It's not part of a navigationController, so I guess that's where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Then use a UIToolbar instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `LoginWebViewController` won't be a part of `UINavigationViewController`.

Check your Storyboard file which is the initial view controller. If it's a normal `UIViewController` you need to put a `UINavigationViewController` as your initialViewController. But instead of that I'll suggest adding a `UIToolbar` in your `LoginWebViewController` and set the buttons in it. It'll be good, if you are not doing any navigation in your app (As it's a webview based app)